# Show data value in label from DB, React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show my data value in a label, do I have to use .map every time?

DB Call:

```
const { carId } = useParams();
const { carType, setCarType } = useState([]);

const getCar (carId) => {
   CarTypes.GetCar(carId)
   .then(response) => {
     setCarType(response.data.data);

    }
}

return {
    <h2 className="title"> { carType.CarMake } </h2>


}
```

Is there a different way to do this? I'm not getting an error, but do I need to do the .map to get the value? It's only returning one value.

do I need to do this every time, the response will only has 1 value in it?

```
{ carType.map(data => (
      <h2 className="title"> { carType.CarMake } </h2>
)}
```

Comment: If you have a way to know if you have only a value or more than one, you can avoid it, otherwise if you don't have this knowledge I think you have to use it all the time

Comment: Yes you might have to do it.
It totally depends on the `response.data.data` if it is an array you have to call map on it regardless of its length

Comment: It'll only be one value returned based off of the ID that's passed in. I just want to show the value in a label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **really** sure about it's always going to have **one** element in the array, you can assign it using array definition like the following.

```
const { carId } = useParams();
const [carType, setCarType]  = useState([]);

const getCar (carId) => {
   CarTypes.GetCar(carId).then({data}) => {
      // See array definition like in the useState
      const [singleCar] = data.data;
      setCarType(singleCar);
   }
}

return {
    <h2 className="title"> { carType.CarMake } </h2>
}
```

You can use it like that without using map()

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because, in the first rendering, your state "carType" is empty, so it cannot find the preperty "CarMake", so try this instead :

```
{!!carType.length && 
<h2 className="title"> { carType.CarMake } </h2>
}
```

Comment: It's coming back, if I use the .map, I was asking is there another way to do that with only 1 record coming back? There will always be one and always be a value to come back.

Comment: Try with "setCarType(response.data.data.CarMake )" instead of this "setCarType(response.data.data)"